# How to validate optional parameters in Java 

Tags: java

I've a method which accepts 10 parameters and out of which 8 are mandatory. To check if the 8/10 are having not null values, i've a bunch of if-else statements for every parameter.

Writing this if-else code seems to be inelegant to me. Is there better way to do this?

Thank you
BC

Comment: Ten parameters for a single method, that's inelegant. You'd better refactor and introduce some intermediate objects.

Comment: Are you saying that having *any* 8 parameters non-null is a win? Or are you saying that of the 10, there are 8 specific parameters which must each by non-null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the apache commons-lang library to validate your input parameters:

```
Validate.notNull(param, "This param can not be null"); // the message is optional
```

Comment: The param can also be a object array containing these 8 args and the apache API can be used to validate that the object array doesn't have any null argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a class to encapsulate the parameters. That way, in your class, you can have a method checking for the validity of them.

Something like:

```
class MethodParams {
    private String p01;
    private String p02;
    private String p03;
    private String p04;
    private String p05;
    private String p06;
    private String p07;
    private String p08;
    private String p09;
    private String p10;

    // getter & setters

    public boolean validate() {
        // validate parameters here
    }


}

class A {
    public methodWith10(MethodParams mp) {
        if (!mp.validate()) {
            // do something and fail
        }
        // methodWith10 implementation follows...
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does help some with the issue of the method taking 10 parameters, there are some things I don't like about it. Particularly, it's best to avoid allowing an invalid object to be created in the first place. If a method takes a `MethodParams` argument, it should be able to assume that object is valid because `MethodParams` should enforce its own validity. This also doesn't so much address the need for `if/else`, it just moves them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Guava's [Preconditions.checkNotNull](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull%28T%29) methods are good for this.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that the following is advanced and that it requires the use of 3rd party jars, but take a look at OVal:

[4.2.2. Declaring constraints for method parameters](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#preconditions)

for example:

```
@Guarded 
public class BusinessObject
{
  public void setName(@NotNull String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: this is intriguing and look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If the nested if..else statements are what's bothering you, you can check the parameters one at a time and return immediately after the first one fails.

So, something like this:

```
if (firstParm == null) {
  err = "firstParam is required.";
  return false;
}

if (secondParam == null {
  err = "secondParam is required.";
  return false;
}

// If we made it this far, we have all the required parameter values
```

You, of course, notice the drawback of this method, which is that the caller won't know that the second parameter is required until they pass in a valid first parameter. However, this type of implementation is common.

To improve this, you can get a bit more fancy like this:

```
err = "";
boolean ok = true;

if (firstParm == null) {
  err = "firstParam is required.";
  ok = false;
}

if (secondParam == null {
  err = err + " secondParam is required.";
  ok = false;
}

if (! ok) {
  return false;
}

// If we made it this far, we have all the required parameter values
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? Rather than "a bunch of if-else statements for every parameter", there is one ternary op for each parameter:

```
  public static void foo(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g, String h, String i, String j) {
    int validCount = 0;
    validCount += (a != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (b != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (c != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (d != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (e != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (f != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (g != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (h != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (i != null) ? 1 : 0;
    validCount += (j != null) ? 1 : 0;

    if(validCount < 8)
      System.out.println("Invalid");
    else
      System.out.println("Valid");
  }
```